# How to config mongo on a remote server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have two servers, one for app(rails) and one for db(mongo).My rails config for mongo will be like this(yaml file):

```
hosts:
  - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:57777
database: admin
username: root
password: some_password
```

So.. how can I configure on the mongo server including the `57777` port, password for root user?

**Update**

I tried to change the password but in vain:

```
$ mongo
> use admin
> db.changeUserPassword("root", "new_password")
Error: Updating user failed: User root@admin not found at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1105
```

Comment: Do you have a replicated/sharded setup or a standalone instance of mongod??

Comment: @vmr I think not, I just install mongodb on the server, then don't know what to do next. I tried to change the password but in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to create a user with the following command on mongo shell:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "root",
      pwd: "some_password",
      roles: [
         { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }
      ]
    }
)
```

You can then stop mongo server(kill). Now start mongo server with the command : `mongod --port 57777 -u root -p some_password --authenticationDatabase admin`

Comment: Thanks for this. Can I save the port so that I can use the port when I  restart the server or mongodb next time?

Comment: Yes you can save the port and other params in a config file and start mongod with --config configFileName. Please accept the answer if you find it useful so that others can reference it.